# Unix: Cut string by regex delimiter

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, cut

I have function that prints out the longest path in directory tree. Let's say the function prints this: `./.mozilla/firefox/z6upkljn.default/storage/permanent/chrome/idb/2918063365piupsah.files`

What I want to do is to cut this string after match with user defined regex.

For example if user puts in regex like: `*de?a*`, the only match is `z6upkljn.default`. So at the end, the output will be `./.mozilla/firefox`

Here is a code sample I found `sed 's/My_expression.*//'` 
Where the My_expression is **regular expression** and **delimiter** for cutting defined by user.

It works for this input `$echo /homes/eva/xm/xmikfi00 | sed 's/mik.*//'`, where for output I get `/homes/eva/xm/x`. As expected.

But if I enter simple regex `$echo /homes/eva/xm/xmifki00 | sed 's/mi?.*//'`, the output is `/homes/eva/xm/xmikfi00`. Anyone who can help me how to get the same output as in the previous example?

I'll be glad for any help or suggestions, thanks.

Comment: What's the rule for delimitation here ?

Comment: Delimitation is defined by user and it could be extended regular expression.

Comment: _regex like: *de?a*, the only match is z6upkljn.default_. What's the rule here ?

Comment: anything that matches the regular expression `*de?a*`

Comment: `*de?a*` isn't a regex, it's a glob expression, you can't use it with sed.

Comment: What you can do is to split your url using `IFS="/"`, then you test each part with `[[ $url = *de?a* ]]` in a loop and you append the parts to a result array until you obtain a match. After you only need to join the result array with a slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed uses (by default) POSIX BREs, not EREs. If what you're trying to match with your `?` is "any character", use a `.`: `echo /homes/eva/xm/xmifki00 | sed 's/mi..*//'`.

See `man 7 re_format` for more details.

Comment: So is there any possible solution how to make it EREs-friendly?

Comment: Yes. Write your own code using sh, bash, perl, python, etc. that calls the 'glob' library for that language. Or translate globs into regexes - it isn't difficult. Probably you should `man bash` to get a sense of how globbing works.

Comment: Yes, although its non-standard. BSD-based `sed`s have an `-E` option, and GNU `sed` uses `-r`. Still, neither of these would enable `?` to match any character, however; that's not a feature of either flavor of POSIX regex syntax.

Comment: And as mentioned above, your example is indeed a glob, and not a regular expression of any dialect I am familiar with.